# Python: Efficient way to find the average tetrahedron clustering coefficient for a graph?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx

I am aware of the standard clustering coefficient (which is for based on number of actual triangles through a node by number of possible triangles). I am looking for an appropriate way to do this for tetrahedrons (4-node complete subgraph/ 4-clique subgraph). Essentially, this would, again, mean finding all the tetrahedron through some given point divided by number of possible tetrahedrons through that point and averaging for all points.

I looked at [this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.clustering.html#networkx.algorithms.cluster.clustering) and [this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.average_clustering.html#networkx.algorithms.cluster.average_clustering) to see if I could replicate for my own case, but found it hard to understand what's going on (since I am relative new to python/networkx).

What would be an efficient way to do this for thousands nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single node you could do something like:

```
nb = G.subgraph(G.neighbors(N))
cc = 0 if len(nb) < 3 else 2 * sum(networkx.triangles(nb).values()) / (len(nb) * (len(nb)-1) * (len(nb)-2))
```

For the average you could use clique enumeration. I couldn't find how to only get tetrahedra from `networkx` so we use `itertools.groupby` to filter them. Then we just count how often each node occurs in this list, normalize, take the average and that's it.

```
import collections
import networkx
import itertools

def ff3(x):
    return x*(x-1)*(x-2)

def avg_tetr_cc(g):
    tetrahedra = itertools.islice(itertools.groupby(
        networkx.enumerate_all_cliques(g), len), 3, 4)
    try:
        tetrahedra = next(tetrahedra)[1]
    except StopIteration:
        return 0
    cnts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*tetrahedra))
    return 6 * sum(cnt / ff3(g.degree[v]) for v, cnt in cnts.items()) / len(g)


# demo
f = networkx.complete_graph(10)
g = networkx.erdos_renyi_graph(2000, 0.1)

print(avg_tetr_cc(f))
print(avg_tetr_cc(g))
```

Sample output:

```
1.0
0.000998169690313529
```